# Nexus - new installation causes errors - nexus-3.13

Tags: nexus, nexus3

Without doing much pre-config installation on Nexus 3.13, on a new install, the install won’t start and throwing out errors during the “Apply upgrade” section. Here’s what I’m seeing:

```
2018-09-04 16:13:46,376+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl - Upgrade component from 1.9 to 1.10
2018-09-04 16:13:46,377+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl - Upgrade component from 1.10 to 1.11
2018-09-04 16:13:46,384+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel <query>select from repository where recipe_name in ['docker-hosted', 'docker-proxy']</query>]  *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - Exception `37EC5983` in storage `plocal:/opt/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config`: 2.2.36 (build d3beb772c02098ceaea89779a7afd4b7305d3788, branch 2.2.x)
....
....
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class 'REPOSITORY' was not found in database 'config'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new install. I’m assuming something occurred in the install process and created files in the /opt/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus3 directory then when I went to start nexus again things just didn’t play nice.

I removed the contents from /opt/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus3 and it worked.